# Pythonic search in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, search, dictionary

I have a dictionary structure as follows:

{ID : [{*}, {*}, {*}, ...]}

i.e, each ID have a list of dictionaries, each of them representing an action in a game. The content of each of this dictionary (represent by *) is structured by these keys, and the list is **ordered** by the `gameTime` field:

```
userID  gameTime    gameCode    shortDesc   d01   d02   d03   d04   chapter   level   playCnt
```

I have to write a .csv file filled with the data corresponding to *userIDs* that met some conditions. I.e., I have to store the data related to users that, at some point, took some actions.
For example, I have to have the information related to each *userID* that at some point had these key/values:

> shortDesc : BADGE_OPT
>
> d01 : OPT-IN

As `d01` is a data related to `shortDescription`, I know that when I found `shortDesc : BADGE_OPT` I have to look at `d01 : OPT-IN`

However I can also found a sequence of:

> shortDesc : BADGE_OPT / d01 : OPT-IN
>
> shortDesc : BADGE_OPT / d01 : OPT-OUT

Then, I have to store just information when the `d01 = OPT_IN`, i.e., the information between any `d01 = OPT_OUT / d01 = OPT_IN` must be discard.

So, there are to cases, the `BADGE_OPT` is turned on and it was never turned out. Or I can found a sequence of turn in / turn out.

I know that I can iterate over my list of dictionaries, start recording (in another list) when I first find `d01 = OPT_IN`, stop when I find `d01 = OPT_OUT` and so on. But I wondering if there is a *pythonic* way to do this (get these specifics parts or information, or delete the unnecessary ones).

So far I was trying something like this:

```
import numpy
import csv
import fileinput
import sys

from itertools import chain

def process_data(file_path):
    users = {}
    
    # Open the .csv file and creates a dict of actions
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for row in spamreader:
            conditions = list(row[condition_name[i]] == condition_value[i] for i in range(len(condition_name)))
            if row[event_name] == event_value and all(conditions) == True:  
                # Add an empty list for 'userID' if it is not registered yet in dict
                user = row['subjectID']
                actions = users.get(user, [])
                # Delete the 'userID' from the information
                del row['subjectID']
                # Add a register of actions for this user
                actions.append(row)
                # Update its values
                users[user] = actions
            
    # Sort each list of actions based on time
    for user, event_list in users.iteritems():
        users[user] = sorted(event_list, key=lambda k: k[data])
         
    # Write a .csv to be consumed by the app    
    with open('eventsInput.txt', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        # Key is the user ID
        # Value is a list of dictionaries of its action per time
        for user, event_list in users.iteritems():
            events = []
            # Produces pairs of event/time
            for event_dict in event_list:
                event = " ".join(event_dict[e] for e in event_fields)
                time = event_dict[data]
                events.append(event)
                events.append(time)
            writer.writerow([user, 1, 2, 0, 4, str(5)] + events)
            
    # Pos-processing
    if len(pos_condition_name) == 0:
        return
        
    f = fileinput.input('eventsInput.txt', inplace=True)
    w = csv.writer(sys.stdout) 
    spamreader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for row in spamreader:
        conditions = list(row[pos_condition_name[i]] == pos_condition_value[i] for i in range(len(pos_condition_name)))
        if all(conditions) == True:
            w.writerow(row)

event_name = 'shortDesc'
event_value = 'ANGLE_RULE_ACTION'
event_fields = ['d01', 'd02', 'd03', 'd04']
condition_name = ['level', 'chapter']
condition_value = ['3', '3']
pos_condition_name = ['shortDesc']
pos_condition_value = ['BADGE_OPT']
```

But this doesn't work at least for two reasons. First, it's not necessary that each dictionary have the field `shortDesc = BADGE_OPT` and `d01 = OPT_IN`. This would not even make sense in this data. However, I cannot test using `any` because the condition may be turned out later, and I have to store only the information relative to the period in which the condition value was `in`.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the outside part of the solution is best addressed with a couple of particularly pythonic for loop constructs:

```
for id,actionlist in bigdict.items():
   opted_in=False  # initial state

   for index,stardict in enumerate(actionlist):
      if stardict['shortDesc'] == 'BADGE_OPT':
          if ( stardict['d01'] == 'OPT-IN') opted_in = True
          if ( stardict['d01'] == 'OPT-OUT' opted_in = False

      # act depending on opted_in state
```

It looks clumsy, but I've avoided `opted_in = ( stardict['d01'] == 'OPT-IN' )` because it's not clear that d01 is constrained to have those two values only. You might put the last three lines in a `try ... except KeyError` block if it's possible for a `stardict` to not contain `shortDesc` or `d01` keys.

So what to do? I'd build an outdict out of stardicts while opt_in is true, but I may not fully understand the problem. So

```
 outdict={}

 for id,actionlist in bigdict.items():

   opted_in=False  # initial state
   outdict[id] = [] 

   for index,stardict in enumerate(actionlist):
      if stardict['shortDesc'] == 'BADGE_OPT':
          if ( stardict['d01'] == 'OPT-IN') opted_in = True
          if ( stardict['d01'] == 'OPT-OUT' opted_in = False
      if opted_in:
          outdict[id].append( stardict)
```

and then process outdict. Note, there is no copying of stardicts, simply assigning the same stardicts to new lists stored in a new outdict, so it should be acceptably fast.

NB not tested.

Comment: Yes, that looks like my currently solution. (: I was wondering if there was some `pythonic` magic using list comprehension and so on. Thank you.